# TypeScript: How to apply a map function on typings?

Tags: typescript, typing

Currently, I have kind of the following types:

```
type Value = boolean | number | string

class Struct<T extends Value[] = Value[]> {

    constructor(fmt: string) { }

    pack(...args: T): Buffer { }

}
```

I would like to know how to replace `<???>` by a list of the `Value[]` used by each `Struct` passed to the constructor in the following snippet:

```
class StructConcat<T extends Struct[]> {

    constructor(...structs: T) { }

    pack(...args_list: <???>) { }

}

// example:
const a: HeadStruct = new Struct<[number]>('<I')
const b: VectorStruct = new Struct<[number, number, number]>('<3f')
const concat = new StructConcat(a, b)
```

Ultimately, the `StructConcat.pack` function should be constrained such has:

```
concat.pack([1], [2, 3, 4])
```

So far, the best I could do was: `(T[number] extends Struct<infer K> ? K : never)[]` but in the scenario just above, it outputs `([number] | [number, number, number])[]` which is close, but still not: `[[number], [number, number, number]]`.

Does TypeScript's typing system allow such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tuples in mapped types starting in 3.1:

```
type Value = boolean | number | string

class Struct<T extends Value[] = Value[]> {

    constructor(fmt: string) { }

    pack(...args: T): Buffer { }

}

type ExtractValueFromStruct<T> = T extends Struct<infer V> ? V : never
type MapStructTuple<T extends Struct[]> = { 
    [P in keyof T]: ExtractValueFromStruct<T[P]>
}

class StructConcat<T extends Struct[]> {

    constructor(...structs: T) { }

    pack(...args_list: MapStructTuple<T>) { }

}

// example:
const a= new Struct<[number]>('<I')
const b= new Struct<[number, number, number]>('<3f')
const concat = new StructConcat(a, b)
concat.pack([1], [1, 2, 3])
concat.pack([1], [1, 2, 3, 4]) // err
```

Comment: @WKnight02 glad to help :)